# How can I connect with address using asyncio open_connection function

Tags: python, connection, python-asyncio

I would like to connect with several address using asyncio library, like 
'127.0.0.1:8000/hello'

But where can I put '/hello' part ? and how can I call this part? (endpoint? static url? )

```
asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8000)
```

Answer (score 2):

> But where can I put `/hello` part ?

[`asyncio.open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) opens a raw TCP connection to the given remote endpoint. The address of the form `127.0.0.1:8000/hello` strongly indicates an HTTP connection. HTTP is a protocol built on top of TCP, where you connect to the given host and port (`127.0.0.1` and port 8000 in your case) using TCP and send a *request* in a specified format, and to which the server answers with a *response*.

HTTP communication is a complex topic and is not something you want to implement from scratch. Fortunately there are mature asyncio-aware libraries that handle it for you, such as [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp). Using that library connecting to a server might look like this:

```
import aiohttp, asyncio

async def connect_to(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.data()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        data = connect_to('http:/127.0.0.1:8000/hello')
        # do something with data, or connect to other urls

asyncio.run(main())
```

> and how can I call this part? (endpoint? static url? )

That part is typically called the *path* of the URL, see e.g. section 3.3 of [the RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for more details.